# Fetching data from server & adding notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am working on an app which fetches student info from a server, like absences and events and grades. I have no access to the server, I only have the API. 
I am asked to implement push notifications in the app, such that if a teacher marks a student absent, that student get a notification about that. I searched and found several approaches:

1- Background fetch: I tried using background fetch to check if the student logged in to the app was marked absent today, if yes, show a local notification. It worked when I simulated w background fetch, but never worked on the physical device.

2- I searched for using Apple Push Notification Service, and they all wanted me to build a server, and I dont know how to start. Can I build a server which pushes notifications to devices in a way facebook does it? That is, one user triggers a notification at another user, in other words: I dont want to use broadcast notifications.

3- Using third party, like backendless, firebase or any alternatives. Would that be a useful approach?

Comment: Using a server is probably best.  It would be better if the server that was actually recording the absence could initiate the push, but as that isn't an option you will need to poll the server periodically

Comment: I dont know from where to start. Should i buy a Server? Or could i just use my laptop as a server? Which language do I have to use on the server side?

Comment: Previously I would have suggested parse.com, now perhaps backendless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Backendless your app (on the student side) can register itself to receive push notifications. This is done with an API call that registers the device on the servers provided by Backendless. Then you would build an additional application (could be a browser web app or a mobile app) for the teachers. The system allows to send targeted notifications, so when a student is marked as absent, you could use the API to deliver a push notification specifically to the student's device. Would be happy to discuss in detail, you can post your question to the [Backendless support forum](http://support.backendless.com).

Comment: I have 3 versions of the app: one for the admin, whom I want to send broadcast notifications (to all students and employees). Another for teachers which must send notifications to students (absence, fee due, grades) and a third one for the student, which must have the ability of receiving all these notifications. Is that all possible using backendless?

Answer (score 1):

For my app I have designed Push service using **Java APNS library**.
Or You could use Microsoft Azure Mobile services to push a notifications to devices.

Comment: So I can design my own server, such that I can let one user send another user a notification?

Comment: Your requirement is to send notification to specific users, you need to maintain a table in your server to store  devicetoken,username,enable/disabled flag.  Also you need to write a service to push the devicetoken and username once user says Yes to receive push notification pop up.